# Boot splash progress indicator screen missing from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS during boot

Tags: 18.04, grub2, plymouth

When I boot into Ubuntu, I see the GRUB menu, but do not see the default Ubuntu boot splash progress indicator screen after that.  The screen just stays purple while booting until I see the LightDM screen to type in my password.  How do I get the default Ubuntu boot splash screen to appear (the one with those 5 indicator dots)?

The contents of my /etc/default/grub are identical to other Ubuntu 18.04 LTS systems I have which do show the boot splash, namely,

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I opened Synaptic to ensure plymouth related items were installed (plymouth, plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo, plymouth-label, plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text, libplymouth4). I reinstalled them again anyway, but it didn't help.

I then checked the contents of  /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ and compared it with another 18.04 system and the files are the same.

Most searches online for this issue are related to removing the splash, so not much came up in my search, except this from 2012, ***The mystery of the missing boot splash screen***: https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-fix-ubuntu-boot-splash-screen-after-grub-updates

That link suggests the issue is due to a variable called $vt_handoff in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file. Apparently this variable blacklists graphic cards and incorrectly decides that I should not use a graphical boot screen. The link goes on to say the solution is to edit grub.cfg and remove all $vt_handoff references in the code.  I suspect those directions are for a different version of GRUB or UBUNTU because that file doesn't exist on my 18.04 LTS system.

Does anyone know how I can get the boot splash screen back with that pseudo progress indicator?

I don't know exactly when the splash screen disappeared. I have an Apple MacPro 2,1 desktop tower with 32-bit UEFI and 64-bit processor. The latest +mac iso image for this oddball configuration is 14.04.4 LTS. So just today, I installed 14.04, then upgraded to 16.04, then upgraded to 18.04 LTS.  I am using the Unity-Desktop.

EDIT1: I should point out that on shutdown, I ***do*** see the splash indicator, just not on boot-up.

EDIT2: Using an ATI HD5000 series graphics card w/Mac firmware.

EDIT3: The boot splash screen did show when I had Ubuntu 16.04 installed on an old HDD on this same computer.

EDIT4: [image: Added a photo of what GRUB2 boot menu settings look like when I press E]